# AES encryption of JPG/Zip files in Java

Tags: java, encryption, jpeg, aes

I'm writing two programs; one that encrypts a file given in the first argument, with a ASCII seed given in the second argument, and another that decrypts the encrypted file. The algorithm uses AES-128 in CBC stream cipher mode. The file is read into a buffer, a SHA-1 hash is produced and attached to the plaintext, and then encrypted. The seed is also produced by SHA-1. The program that decrypts (using the same seed) separates the message from the digest and compares the digest with a locally produced hash.
So far, the two programs work perfectly for a .txt file, but if I try to encrypt/decrypt a .jpg or .png file, all that is left of the original image is a small part of the top - the rest is just random colors. .zip files come out corrupted.

My code is pretty large, my apologies.

encrypt:

```
public class secureFile 
{
private static SecretKeySpec sec_key_spec;
private static Cipher sec_cipher;
private static final int SIZE_LIMIT = 1024;
private static final int SHA1_SIZE = 20;


// encryption function
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plaintext) throws Exception
{
    byte[] encrypted = null;
    byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    try {
        //set cipher object to encrypt mode
        sec_cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sec_key_spec, ivspec);

        //create ciphertext
        encrypted = sec_cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return encrypted;
}


//creates SHA-1 message digest
public static byte[] createDigest(byte[] message) throws Exception
{
    byte[] hash = null;
    try{
        //create message digest object
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");

        //make message digest
        hash = sha1.digest(message);    
    }
    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
        System.out.println(nsae);
    }
    return hash;
}


public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception 
{   
    byte[] key;
    byte[] key128;
    FileInputStream mFile;
    FileOutputStream cFile;
    byte[] ciphertext;
    byte[] plaintext;
    byte[] sha1_hash;   
    byte[] message;
    String cFilename;
    int file_size;

    try {
        //gets filenames and fileinput
        String[] mFilename = args[0].split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)");
        cFilename = mFilename[0] + "EN." + mFilename[1];
        mFile = new FileInputStream(mFilename[0] + "." + mFilename[1]);

        //limits buffer size to 1024
        file_size = mFile.available();
        if (file_size > SIZE_LIMIT) {
            file_size = SIZE_LIMIT;
        }

        //reads message file in buffer
        message = new byte[file_size];
        mFile.read(message);
        mFile.close();

        //creates sha1 digest from message
        sha1_hash = createDigest(message);

        //combines message and digest
        plaintext = new byte[file_size + SHA1_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < file_size; i++) {
            plaintext[i] = message[i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < SHA1_SIZE; j++) {
            plaintext[file_size + j] = sha1_hash[j];
        }

        //generates key
        key = createDigest(args[1].getBytes("us-ascii"));
        key128 = Arrays.copyOfRange(key, 0, 16);
        sec_key_spec = new SecretKeySpec(key128, "AES");

        //enciphers the plaintext
        sec_cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        ciphertext = encrypt(plaintext);

        //copies ciphertext to file
        cFile = new FileOutputStream(cFilename);
        cFile.write(ciphertext);
        cFile.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

}
```

decrypt file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class decryptFile
{
private static SecretKeySpec sec_key_spec = null;
private static Cipher sec_cipher = null;
private static final int SHA1_SIZE = 20;


//decryption function
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] ciphertext) throws Exception{
    byte[] decrypted = null;
    byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    try{
        //set cipher to decrypt mode
        sec_cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sec_key_spec, ivspec);

        //do decryption
        decrypted = sec_cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
    }
    catch (BadPaddingException b)
    {
        sec_cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sec_key_spec, ivspec);
        decrypted = sec_cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return decrypted;
}


//creates digest
public static byte[] createDigest(byte[] message) throws Exception
{
    byte[] hash = null;
    try{
        //create message digest object
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");

        //make message digest
        hash = sha1.digest(message);    
    }
    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
        System.out.println(nsae);
    }
    return hash;
}


//compares two digests
public static String compareDigests(byte[] digest, byte[] local_digest)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SHA1_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (digest[i] != local_digest[i]) {
            return "Digests don't match; your file may have been tampered with.";
        }
    }
    return "Digests match!";
}


public static void main (String args[]) 
{
    FileInputStream cFile;
    FileOutputStream mFile;
    byte[] key;
    byte[] key128;
    byte[] ciphertext;
    byte[] decrypted;
    byte[] message;
    byte[] digest;
    byte[] local_digest;
    byte[] local_digest2;
    String mFilename;
    int file_size;

    try {
        //obtains filenames
        String[] cFilename = args[0].split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)");
        mFilename = cFilename[0] + "DE." + cFilename[1];
        cFile = new FileInputStream(cFilename[0] + "." + cFilename[1]);

        //reads ciphertext file
        cFile = new FileInputStream(cFilename[0] + "." + cFilename[1]);
        ciphertext = new byte[cFile.available()];
        cFile.read(ciphertext);
        cFile.close();

        //generates key
        key = createDigest(args[1].getBytes("us-ascii"));
        key128 = Arrays.copyOfRange(key, 0, 16);
        sec_key_spec = new SecretKeySpec(key128, "AES");

        //deciphers the plaintext
        sec_cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        decrypted = decrypt(ciphertext);

        //splits plaintext between message and digest
        file_size = decrypted.length;
        message = Arrays.copyOfRange(decrypted, 0, (file_size - SHA1_SIZE));
        digest = Arrays.copyOfRange(decrypted, (file_size - SHA1_SIZE), file_size);

        //compares digests
        local_digest = createDigest(message);
        System.out.println(compareDigests(digest, local_digest));

        //copies message to file
        mFile = new FileOutputStream(mFilename);
        mFile.write(message);
        mFile.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
 }
}
```

I very much appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you!

Comment: From a maintainability and design perspective, you should split the encryption/decryption parts from the rest of your application. We do not have the time here to do a full review of your code. I see particularly troublesome issues with the code that reads in the image for instance, but that has little to do with encryption/decryption.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. The images are bigger than my buffer size, LOL.

Comment: Yeah, it had to be something like that. Don't be afraid to delete the question if you think it is not directly of use to someone else. Glad you figured it out! Please note that SHA-1 is not the correct algorithm to provide integrity, you should be using a (H)MAC over the ciphertext instead, preferably using a second key.